# Adding zero in front of a number python

Tags: numbers, addition, zero

I am making program which will go through all possible choices.

Range is from 00000 to 99999.

For example:

00001,00002...01000,01001,01002...99999.

The problem is that i can make string as '00000' but as i convert it to int in order to add extra 1 to keep cycle going only one 0 appears. In that case i will get 0+1 = 1 and i need 00001.

Not completely sure how should i do it with lists because i might need it in the future for certain operations (to get one element from a current number 00450, 01004, 94571...)

Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: I'm not really sure what your problem is. Are you struggeling to display any number with a number of leading zeros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but you can use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). For example, this will turn `int('00000') + 1` into `'00001'`:

`new_i = '%05d'%(int('00000')+1)`

where `%05d` adds as many trailing zeros as necessary to whatever comes after `%` so the total length of the final string formatted number is 5.

Answer (score 3):

You can use zfill(num) on strings to add leading zeros

```
def convert_int(number,decimals) :
    return str(number).zfill(decimals)

print convert_int(1,6) #prints 000001
```